# Razor Pages .Net Core - Passing parameter via JQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a call to a controller action as follows:

```
$("#refreshResults").load("/Search?handler=RefreshSearchResults");
```

Which hits the following method in the code behind:

[image]

However, I want to be able to pass a string value to the action as follows:

[image]

I have tried a few things but nothing seems to hit the Action, let alone pass the searchText value:

```
$("#refreshResults").load("/Search?handler=RefreshSearchResults?searchText=" + searchValue);
$("#refreshResults").load("/Search?handler=RefreshSearchResults", { searchText: searchValue } );
```

where searchValue is a variable containing a string.
I have also created an identical method to catch any POST calls in case it is trying to POST instead of GET:

[image]

But just cant seem to be able to figure this out.

I am guessing the problem may be to do with the fact I am using the handler on the .load() call in Javascript but cannot be certain.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the first example change the second `?` to a `&`: `$("#refreshResults").load("/Search?handler=RefreshSearchResults&searchText=" + searchValue);`

Comment: ? = start query parameters, & join multiple parameters

Comment: Ahhhhhhh of course!! lol Thank you so much for pointing out that silly mistake! If you wanted to add that as an answer I will accept as the answer.